# WordPress Conditional if_page not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, conditional-statements

my Conditional PHP is not working and i dont know why. Can you help me?

Here the Code:

```
<?php 
if( is_page(array('5279','4945') ))
{
echo '<a href="http://www.example.de/"><img src="http://www.example.de/logo_with_text.png"></a>';
}

elseif( is_page(array('5656','5668','5672','5677','5682','5690','5735','5738','5741','5744','5749','5752')))
{
echo '<a href="http://www.example.de/"><img src="http://www.example.de/logo_with_text_and_icon.png"></a>';
}
else
{
echo '<a href="http://www.example.de/"><img src="http://www.example.de/logo_without_text.png"></a>';
}
?>
```

But i need it in this way... (letters are the Pages ids)

For pages a,b,c,d i need a own logo 
For pages e,f,g,h i need a own logo 
For pages j,k,l,m i need a own logo 
and for Page n,o,p,q i need a own logo

Comment: What exactly is the issue with your code? Does it not work at all? Give you an error message? Show the wrong thing? The right thing, in the wrong place?

Comment: Are you sure your page ID is 5279? Seems quite large

Comment: Yes, page id in wordpress is 5279.

The problem is, that i dont get the Image from the "else" condition placed in the webside.

Only if (is page...) and elseif are working.

Comment: @emitremmus - What do you get if the page_id _isn't_ in your `if` or `elseif` arrays, in that case?

Comment: The real problem is, that i need FOUR conditional statements. And i only have three here.

I need it in this way:
if page id is 1,2,3 then load image 1.png
if page id is 4,5,6 then load image 2.png
if page id is 7,8,9 then load image 3.png
if page id is rest, then load image 4.png

Comment: @emitremmus - why can't you add an extra `elseif`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, literally just tidied it slightly and removed the quotation marks round the page numbers.

```
<?php 
if(is_page(array(5279,4945) ))
{
    echo '<a href="http://www.example.de/"><img src="http://www.example.de/logo_with_text.png"></a>';
}
elseif(is_page(array(5656,5668,5672,5677,5682,5690,5735,5738,5741,5744,5749,5752)))
{
    echo '<a href="http://www.example.de/"><img src="http://www.example.de/logo_with_text_and_icon.png"></a>';
}
else
{
    echo '<a href="http://www.example.de/"><img src="http://www.example.de/logo_without_text.png"></a>';
}
?>
```

Just make sure you have the right pages. To do this go to pages in the dashboard and hover over the link to the page you want, you should see it shows the id number in the url, ie post=100. This is the id for that page and the one you will need to use. Using the id means that regardless of the page name, this code will always work for you.

An extreme test would also be using the below instead of the else

```
elseif(!is_page(array(5279,4945,5656,5668,5672,5677,5682,5690,5735,5738,5741,5744,5749,5752)))
{
    echo '<a href="http://www.example.de/"><img src="http://www.example.de/logo_without_text.png"></a>';
}
```

Comment: I need the condition in this way...

if page is 1,2,3 then image1.png
if page is 4,5,6 then image2.png
if page is 7,8,9 then image3.png
if page is 10,11,12 then image4.png

Comment: I would try `echo 'hello';` for the else statement as this may be as simple as an image not being loaded. Please clarify though what you see on other pages. Do you see an image? No image? One of the images already used?

Comment: the first two conditions are working if(is_page...) and elseif. only "else" is not working. i dont get a image here placed on the side.

Comment: Ok then it could potentially be an image issues, just try `echo 'hello';` for the else instead of the image and confirm if this works.

Comment: Ok then the issue must be to do with the image you are trying to show. Either it is not on the server or the path is incorrect. Before messing with this though, try pressing CTRL+F5 if on windows/CMD+F5 for mac. This does a refresh whilst clearing the cache, do this a few times in case the page is cached. Also try to navigating directly to the image via the url to ensure it is present.